# $(document).ready not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have got a little stuck I have just moved my jQuery CDN to the bottom of the page as instructed.

this script worked perfectly when I had my jquery files at the top of the page:

```
if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
    $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:728px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
} else if (($(window).width() < 800) && ($(window).width() >= 500)) {
    $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe  src="http://www.yahoo.com" scrolling="no" style="width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
} else { 
    $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<div class="Ads-Responsive"><iframe  src="src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:320px; height:50px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>');
}
```

So when I put my Jquery CDN to the bottom of the page in the footer I wrapped my script in $document.ready thinking it would wait for the Jquery sources to load before running scripts above it but nothings happening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:728px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
    } else if (($(window).width() < 800) && ($(window).width() >= 500)) {
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe  src="http://www.yahoo.com" scrolling="no" style="width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
    } else { 
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<div class="Ads-Responsive"><iframe  src="src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:320px; height:50px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>');
    }
});
```

can anyone help?

Comment: I think you meant to tag your question for [tag:javascript], not [tag:java]. I've changed the tags for you. If I'm wrong, then you will want to change them back. If I'm right, then you'll want to learn the differences between the two distinct languages.

Comment: What do you mean by `query sources to load `?  If you're waiting for the iframe content to be loaded, you'll need to attach separate `onload` listeners to them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry typo

Comment: Fire up your developer console in chrome and see what network requests are being made and if any errors are being thrown. They will be in console.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem (which was solved by @DigitalD I believe) your 2nd condition doesn't make a lot of sense to me...pretty sure the `($(window).width() >= 500))` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put your jQuery *after* the script tag that loads from the CDN, otherwise `$(document)` won't work at all.

```
<body>
<p>content</p>
<script src="mycdn/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:728px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
    } else if (($(window).width() < 800) && ($(window).width() >= 500)) {
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<iframe  src="http://www.yahoo.com" scrolling="no" style="width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
    } else { 
        $('.col-lg-7, Ads-Container').html('<div class="Ads-Responsive"><iframe  src="src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no" style="width:320px; height:50px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>');
    }
});  
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that $(document.ready would work anywhere as it wouldn't even start until the page had fully loaded ?

Comment: That will only work if `$` is defined, which it won't be until jQuery loads.

Answer (score 0):

How is your script loaded? If it is inline in the `<header>`, maybe put your script in a `.js` file instead and load it after the `jquery` script.